# Concat object array with the same name

Tags: javascript, regex, object, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have an app in vue.js with vuex that implement some modules, what I'm doing is concatenating objects to get some actions, getters, mutations. 
Like this:

```
const files = require.context('../../renderer/', true, /\?*.actions.js|.\?*.getters.js|.\?*.mutations.js$/);
const modulesSrc = {};

files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  modulesSrc[key.replace(/(\.*\/|\.js)/g, '')] = files(key).default;
});

export default modulesSrc;
```

What I get is it:

[image]

---

When I try to change the regex to work by getting only the name of the folder, it goes like this:

```
const files = require.context('../../renderer/', true, /\?*.actions.js|.\?*.getters.js|.\?*.mutations.js$/);
const modulesSrc = {};

files.keys().forEach((key) => {
  modulesSrc[key.replace(/(\.*\/|\.js|actions?|getters?|mutations)/g, '')] = files(key).default;
});

export default modulesSrc;
```

[image]

But inside the element, it only gets the last file, and do not concat it with the others.

---

I want to get these highlight objects (first regex):

[image]

Inside of this output (last regex):

[image]

What can I do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is simpler and doesn't require the additional overhead of regex:

```js
const key = '/home/folder/something/mutations.js'
const filename = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, key.lastIndexOf('.'))
console.log(filename)
```

Comment: I need the name of the folder to create a module for vuex, although, with your code, If I have more than one mutation it I'll discard the last one.